# How to get the slackapi post results back from Flask to slackchannel?

Tags: flask, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I am trying to use /slash command in slack and pass a variable to a function inside the flask route, but somehow if I put all the functions inside the route it doesn't work but If I kept only the return statement it works.
working condition:

```
from flask import request
from netmiko import Netmiko
from blueprint import blueprint
from app_data import slackapp
from slackpyez.ui import BLOCKS
S1 = {
    "host": "192.168.250.210",
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "admin",
    "device_type": "arista_eos",
    "session_log": "my_session3.txt",
}
net_connect = Netmiko(**S1)
command = "show version"
output = net_connect.send_command(command, use_textfsm=False)
@blueprint.route("/ngrok", methods=["POST","GET"])
def return_show_version():
    return(output)
```

and I can get

[image]

I want to pass a text variable so the ip address would be dynamic but it is not working.

```
from flask import request
from netmiko import Netmiko
from blueprint import blueprint
from app_data import slackapp
from slackpyez.ui import BLOCKS

@blueprint.route("/ngrok", methods=["POST","GET","PUT"])
def return_show_version():
        S1 = {
            "host": request.form["text"],
            "username": "admin",
            "password": "admin",
            "device_type": "arista_eos",
            "session_log": "my_session4.txt",
        }
        net_connect = Netmiko(**S1)
        command = "show version"
        output = net_connect.send_command(command, use_textfsm=False)
        return(output)
```

and here is the result:

```
ngrok failed with the error "operation_timeout"
```

Comment: Where are you seeing that result?  Is there a better traceback in the flask terminal?  I'd start by adding a `print(request.form['text'])` at the beginning of the `return_show_version` function to make sure that variable is what you think it is.  Also I'd check that if you leave `"host": "192.168.250.210",` in that second code sample, does it still fail?

Comment: I am checking the results in the slack channel and flask even it is in debug mode, I can see only the post request was successful although slack says operation timeout. if I hardcoded the ip in the non working scneraio it still doesn't send the response to slackchannel but I can see from the session log file the script is triggered and show version ran on that ip address